# my haystck results are not displaying on the results page

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am new to python and django and I was following a tut with major errata. right now I am trying to get the results page to display my results. This is not my code, it's from a tutorial. Here is my code.

my views.py

```
def post_search(request):

form = request.GET.get('q')
    results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=form)
    # count total results
    total_results = results.count()
    template = 'blog/post/search.html',
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'results': results,
        'total_results': total_results

    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

my search.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Search{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
     {% if request.GET %}
           <h1>Posts containing "{{ form.query }}"</h1>
           <h3>Found {{ total_results }} result{{ total_results|pluralize}}</h3>
           {% for result in results %}
             {% with post=result.object %}
               <h4><a href="{{ post.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
               {{ post.body|truncatewords:5 }}
             {% endwith %}
                 {% empty %}
                <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
           {% endfor %}
           <p><a href="{% url 'blog:post_search' %}">Search again</a></p>
         {% else %}
           <h1>Search for posts</h1>

           <form action="." method="get">
             <div>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="q" id="search" placeholder="search" value="{{ request.GET.q }}">
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">search</button>
                  </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->

                <ul class="list-group" id="search-results" style="margin: 5px 0 0 0; width: 325px">
                </ul>
     </div>

   </form>
     {% endif %}

 {% endblock content%}
```

my post_text.txt

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.tags.all|join:", " }}
{{ object.body }}
```

search_indexes.py

```
from haystack import indexes

from .models import Post


class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
   text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
   publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

   # title_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')
   # content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')

   def get_model(self):
       return Post

   def index_queryset(self, using=None):
       """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
       return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

the only thing that shows on the page after I run a search is

```
Posts containing ""
Found 1 result

Search again
```

and if I do this

```
{{results}}
```

it returns this

```
[<SearchResult: blog.post (pk='2')>]
```

where it says post containing a name will show
found results returns a number which lets me know that the results are working

any and all help or guidance in the right direction is greatful. Tried to read the docs. They seem so vague to me. and as I said I am a novice.and there are only  video on the topic and that with frank hibbert and he uses it with ajax

Comment: Have you deleted any `Post`s recently? `manage.py update_index` without `--remove` flag will not remove records from the index and you can get results for which there is no more object in the database.

Comment: no. the only thing that works is {{results.publish}} THATS IT!! this is super complicated